# Mongo Aggregate excluding records in one table based on if they are found in another

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**apartment table**

```
{
    "_id": "AAA",
    "name": "Apartment AAA"
},
{
    "_id": "BBB",
    "name": "Apartment BBB"
},
{
    "_id": "CCC",
    "name": "Apartment CCC"
},
{
    "_id": "DDD",
    "name": "Apartment DDD"
},
{
    "_id": "EEE",
    "name": "Apartment EEE"
}
```

**booking table**

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "apartmentID": "AAA",
    "checkin": 1490000000,
    "checkout": 1499000000
}
{
    "_id": 2,
    "apartmentID": "BBB",
    "checkin": 1500000000,
    "checkout": 1590000000
}
{
    "_id": 3,
    "apartmentID": "CCC",
    "checkin": 1490000000,
    "checkout": 1499000000
}
{
    "_id": 4,
    "apartmentID": "DDD",
    "checkin": 1500000000,
    "checkout": 1590000000
}
```

I need to find the "`name`" of all "`apartment`" which does NOT have a booking between "`1510000000`" and "`1520000000`"

In this case the result should be:

```
{
    "name": "Apartment AAA"
},
{
    "name": "Apartment CCC"
},
{
    "name": "Apartment EEE"
}
```

Please note Apartment EEE does not have any bookings.

Usually I would get all properties into an array and then get all bookings into an array and then run some loops in javascript to find the available apartments.

**QUESTION:**  Is there a way to to this all in one mongodb aggregate pipeline and just returning the "name" of the available apartments?

My old lookups:

```
db.apartment.aggregate([
{
    $match: {}
},
{ 
    $project: { 
        "name": 1
    }
}


db.booking.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        checkin: {$lte: 1520000000},
        checkout: {$gte: 1510000000}
    }
},
{ 
    $project: { 
        "apartmentID": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$not + $elemMatch` to find if any of the booking for apartment is occupied.

`$elemMatch` to find if there is occupied apartment matching the query criteria followed by `$not` to return apartment documents when there is a no occupied booking.

Something like

```
   db.apartment.aggregate({
    $lookup: {
        from: "booking",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "apartmentID",
        as: "bookings"
    }
   }, {
    $match: {
        "bookings": {
            $not: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    checkin: {
                        $lte: 1520000000
                    },
                    checkout: {
                        $gte: 1510000000
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        name: 1
    }
   })
```

Comment: Veeram strikes again! :-D  I didnt know about $elemMatch.  So you read all apartments, then booking lookup and then do the match AFTER you have the booking. Thats pretty clever, I didnt think about moving the math down. pretty cool actually.  QUESTION: I want to add more $lookups to get data from other tables, should I do that after the $match?

Comment: Yes you can add more stages after $match. It depends on what you are tying to do. Based on that you may need to unwind before you can lookup.

Comment: Cool Veeram - once again I bow my head to you ohh mighty Mongo Master :-))))

Comment: Thank you for kind words but I'm no master to say the least. I'm happy to learn and help others in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.2 you can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator to outer join two collections:

```
db.apartment.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "booking",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "apartmentID",
        as: "booking"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: { path: "$booking", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
},
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
          { "booking": {$exists: false }},
          { "booking.checkin": {$gte: 1520000000} },
          { "booking.checkout": {$lte: 1510000000} }
        ]
    }
},
{
    $group: { _id: "$name" }
},
{
    $project: { _id: 0, name: "$_id" }
}
])
```

Output:

```
{
    "name" : "Apartment AAA"
},
{
    "name" : "Apartment CCC"
},
{
    "name" : "Apartment EEE"
}
```

---

Details:

The first stage creates an outer join of apartments with their bookings. This stage produces results which look like:

```
{
    "_id": "AAA",
    "name": "Apartment AAA",
    "booking": [ 
        {
          "_id": 1,
          "apartmentID": "AAA",
          "checkin": 1490000000,
          "checkout": 1499000000
        },
        {
          "_id": 5,
          "apartmentID": "AAA",
          "checkin": 1500000000,
          "checkout": 1590000000
        },
    ]
}
...
{
    "_id": "EEE",
    "name": "Apartment EEE"
}
```

Note that if apartment AAA would have several bookings, all booking documents would be added to `booking` array of apartments. Also note that apartments without bookings will not have `booking` array. Next, we unwind joined bookings array to get rid of the array and produce flattened apartment object with single booking (if any):

```
{
    "_id": "AAA",
    "name": "Apartment AAA",
    "booking": {
         "_id": 1,
         "apartmentID": "AAA",
         "checkin": 1490000000,
         "checkout": 1499000000
     }
},
{
    "_id": "AAA",
    "name": "Apartment AAA",
    "booking": {
         "_id": 5,
         "apartmentID": "AAA",
         "checkin": 1500000000,
         "checkout": 1590000000
     }
}
...
{
    "_id": "EEE",
    "name": "Apartment EEE"
}
```

Next we do filtering and group filtered results by apartment name (because one apartment can have several bookings which do not fall into given range). And the last stage - projecting.

Comment: Hmm this one would give me the opposite of what I need (I need apartments NOT occupied) and this will give me an `ID` in the `name` instead of the `apartment.name`.  And finally it would also not include `Apartment EEE`

Comment: @torbenrudgaard sorry, missed that part. Now aggregate selects only rooms which don't have bookings or don't have bookings in given range